# GitHub with NetBeans strange contributor

Tags: netbeans, github, git-commit, netbeans-8

I am new to GitHub.

I am using NetBeans 8.0.2.

When i make commit and then push the changes on the GitHub website some strange user (https://github.com/leandroizr) appears as contributor.

When NetBeans asked for username and passowrd i provided mine, why the commits are not appearing from my username ? 
When i make changes from the website, it shows my account.

p.s this is my account https://github.com/milestojkovski

Comment: I'm not sure how NetBeans handles this, but you need to check your `user.email` setting. On the command line, `git config user.email` will show this. You can change it with `git config user.email your@real.email.address`. (You may also want to read up on [configuring Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration).)

Comment: it says: git is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file. :/

Comment: You may not have Git set up for command-line use. Does NetBeans offer a "git console" or something? You should be able to run these commands from there. If not, dig through your NetBeans Git options looking for an email setting.

Comment: I solved it, i added [user]
        name = name
        email = email
to the configuration file of git.
But i still have no idea where the strange user was appearing as the one who does commits.